# Simple Postgres query returning no result

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, left-join

I have two tables:

```
products(id: integer, price: float, website_id: integer)
```

and

```
adjustments(id: integer, product_id: integer, website_id: integer, factor:float)
```

I have indexes on id in both tables, and an index on website_id and product_id on the adjustments table.

This query returns data but it takes some 5 seconds with some 1k products and a couple hundred in adjustments:

```
select 
    products.id, 
    case
    when adjustments.website_id = 1
    then
        products.price+coalesce(adjstments.factor,0)
    else
        products.price
    end as price
from
    products
left join
    adjustments on products.id = adjustments.product_id
where
    products.website_id = 1;
```

This other query however returns no results when there's nothing in the adjustments table:

```
select 
    products.id, 
    products.price+coalesce(adjstments.factor,0) as price
from
    products
left join
    adjustments on products.id = adjustments.product_id
where
    products.website_id = 1 and adjustments.website_id = 1;
```

Was it not supposed to return the data from the first table regardless if there are any matching record in the 2nd table? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filtering in the `where` clause if applied after the join. So here, you get all the rows from `products`, and match them with empty `adjustments` rows (since the table is empty). Then, you apply the `where` condition, that includes `adjustments.website_id = 1` since `adjustment.website_id` is always `null`, no rows are returned.

You could move this condition to the `join` in order to get the behavior you expected:

```sql
select 
    products.id, 
    products.price+coalesce(adjstments.factor,0) as price
from
    products
left join
    adjustments on products.id = adjustments.product_id and adjustments.website_id = 1
where
    products.website_id = 1;
```

Comment: Nice, got it to work, thank you very much. Both seem to take too long, like 5 seconds, guess going to try playing with alternatives.